# Effective form processing using php

Tags: php, ajax, oop

I'm working on some project and I want to process requests from forms in several templates. The question is how is to invoke a proper function in the handling scrip. Although, I've been coding for a while, I still cant come up with anything better then using a variable in a hidden field:

```
if ($_POST['somehiddenfield'] == 1) {
   some_function_1();//doesnt matter if its a function or a method
}

if ($_POST['somehiddenfield'] == 2) {
   $mainclass->somemethod();
}
//goes on indefinitely
```

Also I want to keep everything in a single handler file, where my main class is invoked. So is there a more effective way than using `if ... else`?

Comment: whatabout sending a more reading value (still in a hidden field), that you could compose the method name from? Give each form a specific name.

Comment: Although your question does not relate to AJAX per-say, this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25987/best-way-to-structure-php-ajax-handlers) may relate to your question.

Comment: or have an `arrray(array("type"=>1, "method"=>"personalForm"), array(..))`

Comment: @Jeff Thank you. I like the first Idea more, could you please explain how to compose a method name from a variable in an answer?

Comment: IMO using hidden inputs is perfectly fine. That's pretty much what they are there for. However, I don't generally use them to split off functions in the PHP side. What I usually do is setting a global variable in javascript, thereby determining which function to call through ajax. (So, changing the URL request depending on the function I want to call) - Another way would be to send it as a function parameter if you can. I tend to send ints as parameters (url/class/function/parameter), but you'd need to have routing for that.

Comment: @Babydead Im not against the use of hidden fields per se. I simply want to know how to build a beautiful code. Could you please explain how do you pass a global variable to php script via JS?

Comment: If you are going to go OOP, I'd recommend you start looking at micro-frameworks such as [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/), [SlimFramework](https://www.slimframework.com/), and many others. IMO frameworks will keep your code clean, organized, and maintainable by having controllers (what you are looking for), views, and models.

Comment: @RWS I don't pass a global JS var to PHP. I use the JS var to decide JS-side to which PHP function I'm sending the data. I just change the URL I call depending on whatever that global var is set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep a key=>value array hardcoded with all the possible options. Pass the hidden input field, check if there are any intersections between your post values and the keys of the hardcoded options and call any matching values as functions.

```
$map = [
    'yourHiddenField' => 'myFunctionName',
    'anotherHiddenField' => 'myOtherFunctionName',
    'yourOtherHiddenField' => 'yetAnotherfunctionName',
];

$intersection = array_intersect(array_keys($map), array_keys($_POST));

foreach ($intersection as $key) {
    $this->{$map[$key])();
}
```

This code hasn't been tested.

EDIT: 
Be careful with allowing ANY input to be ran without predefining which functions you should allow to be ran.

**Example of how dangerous it could be even with sanitisation:**

```
class Test {
    public $i = 1;

    function __construct(){
        $this->i++;
    }
}

$formVariable = '__construct';

$t = new Test();

$t->{$formVariable}();

echo $t->i;
```

Comment: An interesting approach. Indeed your example shows how dangerous it is not to sanitize the data, thank you!

Comment: Happy I could help. Never allow users to define exact functions to run - always map things.

Comment: @gonzie don't we generally allow our users to run functions through routing and  `.htaccess`, though? Or would you consider that different? :P

Comment: @Babydead The users run the function you want them to run. All routes are usually predefined and in any event that they're not, they still don't manipulate the code within the files. There's a huge difference between routes and allowing code injections.

Comment: @gonzie just wanted to make sure there's a difference and that my thoughts made sense, ahaha. Thanks!

Comment: Even though both answers by @jeff and are very useful in their own right, I will mark this one as correct, since gonzie has fewer rep. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do the following:

still have a hidden field, but let it contain something like the form name

```
<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="post">
```

Then you can do something like that in the consuming php script:

```
<?php
// whatever class you use... this is just a simple dummy
class FormsProcessor {
      public function post($params) {
          echo "processing post form";
      }
}

$formName = "post";  // would be $formName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST['formName'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
// BUT BE SURE TO SANITIZE THE INPUT!!!

$params = [];  // dummy
$formsProcessor = new FormsProcessor();
                 // here's the trick.
$formsProcessor->{$formName}($params);
// to be even safer you could check first if this method_exists() 
// and/or if it's in a list of allowed methods.
```

Be aware that there mustn't be any other methods in this class that the user shouldn't invoke. You could go around that by really compose the method name of two parts:

```
$methodName = $formName."Processor";
//....
$formsProcessor->{$methodName}();`
```

Comment: "*BUT BE SURE TO SANITIZE THE INPUT!!!*" that part needs more bold and biggerness :)

Comment: @IncredibleHat I'm using PDO, but this advice is always important

Comment: @Jeff This is simple yet elegant. Could you please explain the notation `$formsProcessor->{$formName}($params);`? I do not understand the `{$formName}` part.

Comment: that part parses the variable to the method name. `$formsProcessor->$formName` would not work. Just as you would do in a string `"footext {$bar[2]} moretext";`

Comment: here's the docs: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Be aware that there mustn't be any other methods in this class that the user shouldn't invoke. You could go around that by really compose the method name of two parts: `$methodName = $formName."Processor";` -> $formsProcessor->{$methodName}();`